# LINQPad - How do I filter the list of tables to show only a certain schema?

Tags: linq-to-sql, linqpad

When connecting LINQPad to my SQLServer database, there are 100+ tables returned to the explorer tree in the UI.  I'd like to filter that list so that only tables matching a certain naming convention (or schema) appear.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is the motivation to locate a particular object, speed up the generation of the data context, or just reduce clutter? (Note that LINQPad groups tables by schema.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  You could, of course, query the system tables to generate that list yourself, though that doesn't help with the huge list in the explorer tree.  There is a similar suggestion on LINQPad's UserVoice site: [Search/filter by table or column name](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/966083-search-filter-by-table-or-column-name).  You may consider voting for that.